# Simple way to determine when an process has an open window not just running with powershell?

Tags: powershell, process

I am attempting to work with an exe via powershell.  I have to call the open application and pass some keyboard shortcuts to it because it does not have built in switches unfortunately.  I am using start-process to kick it off and using a do until loop to wait till the app is open to pass the keyboard shortcuts to it.  when I use just get-process "ProcessName"  it exits the loop like 5 seconds before the application window is actually.  I could work around this by using start-sleep for for another 5 or so seconds but am not sure if it will only take that long on other machines. Is there a property I can use from get-process that will only return a value when an application window is actually open?

I have tried

```
start-process -FilePath "Path to exe"
Do{
write-Output "test..."
}
until ((Get-Process -Name "ProcessName" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Responding -eq "True")
```

I have also tried:

```
start-process -FilePath "Path to exe"
Do{
write-Output "test..."
}
until ((Get-Process -Name "ProcessName" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).TotalProcessorTime.Milliseconds -gt "600")
```

The totalprocessor time works when testing but I don't know that number will be accurate on other machines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`user32.dll!EnumDesktopWindows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdesktopwindows) to loop through all windows and then call [`user32.dll!GetWindowThreadProcessId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid) to determine whether any window belongs to the process in question:

```bsh
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class ProcessWindowFinder
{
    private delegate bool WindowDelegate(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
    private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint processId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr hDesktop, WindowDelegate lpfn, IntPtr lParam);

    public static bool FindByPID(uint pid)
    {
        bool found = false;
        ProcessWindowFinder.WindowDelegate filter = delegate(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam)
        {
            if(!found)
            {
                // test whether this window belongs to the target process 
                // if we haven't already found a windows belonging to it
                uint _pid;
                GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out _pid);
                if(pid == _pid)
                    found = true;
            }

            return true;
        };
        EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr.Zero, filter, IntPtr.Zero);

        return found;
    }
}
'@
```

Now you can use it to test whether your process has any desktop windows:

```bsh
# launch file.exe, grab the process object
$process = Start-Process ".\path\to\file.exe" -PassThru

# Wait up to 15 seconds for window
$waitFor = 15
do {
  Write-Host "Waiting for process... "
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
} until ((--$waitFor -lt 0) -or [ProcessWindowFinder]::FindByPID($process.Id) -or $process.HasExited)

if($process.HasExited){
  # process already exited
}
elseif($waitFor -lt 0){
  # timed out waiting for window
}
else{
  # we got a window!
}
```

Comment: Looks like that just waits for 15 and stops.  The window came up around 12 seconds and it was still looping through the do block.  What is that first block of code doing?

Comment: Nevermind, did not see you added the -Passthru paramater.  It looks like it does the same as my other attempts.  It returns a process ID a good 5 or 6 seconds before the window is actually open.

Comment: Looks like i dont need this actually.  $myshell.appactivate("ProcessName") will return false til the window is open it looks like then it activates it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myshell  = New-Object -com "Wscript.Shell"
$process = start-process -FilePath "Path to file" -PassThru

do{
    start-sleep -Milliseconds 500
}
until($myshell.appactivate("ProcessName") -eq "True")
$myshell.appactivate("ProcessName")
$myshell.sendkeys("^{ }")
```